# Are elementfinder promises resolved on declaration?

Tags: protractor, pageobjects

I know that `ElementFinder`s are promises but I'm not sure how the promise behaves if we define the `ElementFinder`s in the beginning of the Page Object. Looking at an example:

```
var EventHeader = function (context) {
    this.eventName = this.moduleRoot.element(by.css('.event-name'));
    this.venueName = this.moduleRoot.element(by.css('.venue-name'));
    this.eventTime = this.moduleRoot.element(by.css('.event-time'));
    this.eventDate = this.moduleRoot.element(by.css('.event-date'));
    this.marketName = this.moduleRoot.element(by.css('.market-name'));
};
```

Will protractor try to resolve all the promises when the page objects is initialised?

I guess the other option would be to define the locators in the beginning and then create methods to return the `ElementFinder` itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element finders will not execute until you call a function on them. You just have to make sure that the elements are on the page when you call something like `click()`, `sendKyes()`, etc.